# simplify function in python to return mean age per product

Tags: python, pandas, function, finance

I have data like so:

```
product|birth-date|id| etc. etc.
_____________________
tv     | 01-01-2000|1|...
book   | 30-04-1980|2|...
```

I want to create a function that sorts product type bought by mean age of the buyer, but as a result return a new data frame with those two columns.

Is there any way to simplify this to be one function instead of two?

The first one aims at creating an age column from the birth date column:

```py
def age(df):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - df.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (df.month, df.day))

df['age'] = pd.to_datetime(df.birth_date)
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: age(x))
df['age'] = df['age'].astype('int')
```

The second function creates a new dataframe that sorts product by age

```py
def create_new_df(df):
   data= df.groupby(['product'])['age'].mean()
   new_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   return new_df

create_new_df(df)
```

Comment: put code in one function and you will have one function instead of two

Answer (score 0):

You can extrapolate the age also in this way:

```py
df["age"] = (
    np.datetime64(dt.date.today()) # convert the datetime object in a numpy.dtype datetime64 array to be able to perform vectorized operation
    - pd.to_datetime(df.birth_date) # get the datetime array that we wish to compute
).astype('<m8[Y]') # we convert the timedelta in Years
```

Slightly less readable (but not so much with comments). It should be faster due to vectorization of operations. As soon as I get home I can compare with some tests.